# sqlite insert using {...} and ? at the same time

Tags: python, sqlite, syntax

I have to following piece of code:

```
temp = item.get() #returns a string
c.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO {tn} ({cn}, {dn}, {en}) VALUES (?, 23, 10)".\
format(tn=table_name, cn=field2, dn = field3, en = field4), (temp))
```

However, the code causes an error:

```
File "First_GUI.py", line 47, in func_confirm
format(tn=table_name, cn=field2, dn = field3, en = field4), (temp))
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current 
statement uses 1, and there are 0 supplied.
```

Do you have any idea how I can fix the syntax?

Comment: It's not the formatting. You'll get the exact same error with the object names as literals in the string. It's the `(temp)`; that's *not a tuple*. Use `(temp,)`.

Comment: I do not really understand your answer. Why is then this possible? temp1 = 'Shell';
    temp2 = 100;
    temp3 = 200;
    c.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO financial_table (Item, Date, Price) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", (temp1, temp2, temp3)) The latter ones are no tuples either.

Comment: See the duplicate. `(temp)` is the same thing as `temp`. It is the comma that makes it a tuple.